# How can I load all parents and eager load childen that filter by parent column?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Parent

| id | parent_value |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| b | 2 |

Children

| parent_id | children_value |
| --- | --- |
| a | 0 |
| a | 0 |
| a | 0 |
| b | 1 |
| b | 2 |

Excepted result

```
[
  {id => 'a', children => []}
  , {id => 'b', children => [children_value => 2]}
]
```

There is a hasMany relation on parent id column.

parent_value and children_value are just normal column they are not fk nor have any defined relation

Can I achieve this by using Parent::with() or Parent->load()?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have defined any **FK** there you need to specify the Foreign and Local keys.

```
public function children() {
  return hasMany(Children::class, 'PARENT_ID', 'ID');
}
```

Using `Parent::with('children')` method you can get your expected result.